# Calling Values from Functions with PouchDB using Find() within a loop

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am trying to loop through the results from a Find() Mango Query and make a all to another function to get extra data to use in my report.

I am looping a list of patient documents from a Find() query but I want to pull in the "last visit" from another list of "visit" documents by calling a function that performs a query but I am having problems.

I can call the function "Get_Static_Value()" and it will return a value however when I send the Patient_ID to the function "Get_Last_Visit(Patient_ID)" then the value comes back as "undefined" although the function is called and will write the "Vist_Date" to the console.

I believe my issue is caused because the promise in the query is not resolving but I am unsure of the syntax to get the value back into my loop once the function has processed.

I read the documement https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html and in the section "Rookie mistake #2: WTF, how do I use forEach() with promises?" I think it identifies my problem with the syntax:

```
db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (result) {

return Promise.all(result.rows.map(function (row) {

return db.remove(row.doc);

}));

}).then(function (arrayOfResults) {

// All docs have really been removed() now!

});
```

However the code above is for alldocs and not find() so I am a little bit stuck on how I process the same method on results from a Find() query.

I have created a JSfiddle to show my code and demonstrate my issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/movitico/gkb89uyf/

```js
// Create the Database
var db = new PouchDB('patient_test');

// Add Patient Documents
function Add_Patients() {
  db.bulkDocs([{
      _id: '1',
      type: 'patient',
      Patient_Name: 'Patient 1',
      Patient_Status: 'Active'
    },
    {
      _id: '2',
      type: 'patient',
      Patient_Name: 'Patient 2',
      Patient_Status: 'Active'
    },
    {
      _id: '3',
      type: 'patient',
      Patient_Name: 'Patient 3',
      Patient_Status: 'Active'
    }
  ]);
}

function Add_Visits() {
  // Add Visit Documents

  db.bulkDocs([{
      _id: 'v1',
      type: 'visit',
      Patient_ID: '1',
      Visit_Date: "06/01/2018"
    },
    {
      _id: 'v2',
      type: 'visit',
      Patient_ID: '1',
      Visit_Date: "05/01/2018"
    },
    {
      _id: 'v3',
      type: 'visit',
      Patient_ID: '1',
      Visit_Date: "02/22/2018"
    },
    {
      _id: 'v4',
      type: 'visit',
      Patient_ID: '2',
      Visit_Date: "02/22/2014"
    },
    {
      _id: 'v5',
      type: 'visit',
      Patient_ID: '2',
      Visit_Date: "02/22/2000"
    },
    {
      _id: 'v6',
      type: 'visit',
      Patient_ID: '2',
      Visit_Date: "02/22/1987"
    }

  ]);
}

function Load_Patients() {

  $('#patient_list').empty();


  db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ['Patient_Name', 'type', 'Patient_Status']
    }
  }).then(function(result) {

    db.find({
      selector: {
        Patient_Name: {
          $gt: true
        },
        type: {
          $eq: 'patient'
        },
        Patient_Status: {
          $eq: 'Active'
        }
      },
      sort: [{
        "Patient_Name": "asc"
      }]
    }, function(error, response) {
      console.log(response);

      for (i in response.docs) {

        var Static_Value = Get_Static_Value();
        var Last_Visit = Get_Last_Visit(response.docs[i]._id);

        $('#patient_list').append('<li>' + response.docs[i]._id + ' ' + response.docs[i].Patient_Name + ' [' + Static_Value + ']' + ' ' + Last_Visit + '</li>');
      }

    })
  });
}

Add_Patients();
Add_Visits();


$('#button_load_patients').unbind().click(function(e) {
  Load_Patients();
});

function Get_Static_Value() {

  return 'I am static';

}

function Get_Last_Visit(Patient_ID) {

  db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ["Visit_Date", "type"]
    }
  }).then(function(result) {
    db.find({
      selector: {
        Visit_Date: {
          $gt: true
        },
        type: {
          $eq: 'visit'
        },
        Patient_ID: {
          $eq: Patient_ID
        }
      },
      sort: [{
        "Visit_Date": "desc"
      }],
      limit: 1

    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.docs.length > 0) {

        Visit_Date = response.docs[0].Visit_Date;

      } else {
        Visit_Date = 'Never';
      }


      console.log(Visit_Date);

      return Visit_Date;

    });
  })
}
```

Once I have returned the "Visit_Date" value then I would manipulate it using MomentJS and include or exclude it from the results that are appended to the div.

I would appreciate any advice on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague I got the solution to this problem and will post the solution as I am sure there are people out there who are as confused as me.

The things that needed to change in my code were that the call to the "Get_Last_Visit" function needed a .then to return the value of the promise. I also needed to add "let i" to make the "i" variable a global variable and available within the function:

```js
for (let i in response.docs) {

  var Static_Value = Get_Static_Value();
  Get_Last_Visit(response.docs[i]._id)
    .then(function(Last_Visit) {
      $('#patient_list').append('<li>' + response.docs[i]._id + ' ' + response.docs[i].Patient_Name + ' [' + Static_Value + ']' + ' ' + Last_Visit + '</li>');
    })
}
```

Here is an updated jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/movitico/9xorLham/